# Join two tables with condition - ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

I wanna join 2 table, games and game_logs. I did it this:

```
game_joins =  Game.joins(:game_logs)
```

It worked. But the thing is I only want to join where the player_id = 1(for example). Column player_id can only be found in table game_logs. So, when I do like this:

```
game_joins =  Game.joins(:game_logs).where(:player_id => 1)
```

Column player_id can't be found, because

```
Game.joins(:game_logs)
```

will result :

```
SELECT games.* FROM games
  INNER JOIN game_logs ON game_logs.game_id= game.id
```

So, the question is what is the possibility I have to filter game_joins with the condition from table game_logs. I hope I explain it well enough. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
game_joins =  Game.joins(:game_logs).where(:game_logs => { :player_id => 1 })
```

Answer (score 1):

In model GameLog you need

```
 belongs_to :game
```

In model Game you need

```
 has_many :game_logs
```

Then one way to modify your query is

```
 game_joins =  Game.joins("left join game_logs on games.id = game_logs.game_id").where("game_logs.player_id = 1").all
```

or you can use

```
  game_joins =  Game.joins(:game_logs).where("game_logs.player_id = 1").all
```