# Rails - Search multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently I've got the following search method for my model

```
class Bike < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :bike_model

  def self.search(search, page)
    fields = [:frame_number]
    order('frame_number ASC').where(fields.map{|f| "#{f} like ?"}.join(' OR '),
                            *fields.map{|f| "%#{search}%"})
  end
end
```

But the attributes of this model are not really searchable (at least not user friendly). I would like to join both foreign table and search them too.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846583/join-two-tables-with-condition-ruby-on-rails) question which probably will solve this problem but it's not generic.

So this is currently my idea:

```
class Bike < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :bike_model

  def self.search(search, page)
    fields = [:frame_number, :customers.lastname]
    joins(:customer).joins(:bike_model).order('frame_number ASC').where(fields.map{|f| "#{f} like ?"}.join(' OR '),
                            *fields.map{|f| "%#{search}%"})
  end
end
```

How do I achieve a generic seach on multiple tables? I would like to get only the bike object in return (with customer_id fits the desired attribute for the customer).

As a bonus I would like to order by customer.lastname, would that work?

```
order('bike_customer.lastname ASC')
```

Comment: What do you mean by generic?

Comment: @frederickCheung I would like to determine the params with the variable and not hard coded in the where method. This way it makes it much easier to add searchable attributes later on. I'm fine with bike_fields, customer_field ect

Comment: If you want to have maximum flexibility, consider using `xapian_db`. This sweet little gem allows you to define search blueprints for each model. You can even weigh the different attributes by relevance. And you can compile additional information to return with each search result. hf :)